# How to simulate guitar strings/chords with Flash's sound synthesizer?

Tags: flash, actionscript, frequency

I've just developed a function to ring frequencies, but I can't make it sound like a guitar string; I can only change it's frequency. Is there some way to change other parameters of a generated sound?

```
function sineGenerateSound(event:SampleDataEvent):void
        {

            for (var i:int=0; i<4092; i++)
            {

                var n:Number = Math.sin((i + event.position) * Math.PI / (44100 / (freq*2) )) * volume;

                event.data.writeFloat(n);
                // sound crackles and pops;
                event.data.writeFloat(n);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [SiON](https://sites.google.com/site/sioncenter), as a good synthesis library, which includes a Guitar Synthesis module which you may find useful, as always YMMV.

Comment: Will I have to use a swc component? I donwloaded it and it's not showing up on the components panel

Comment: I've accomplished it already. Now I can't generate guitar sounds, only simple musical notes. Have someone ever used it before?

Comment: SiON also includes a Guitar Physical modeling synthesizer based on Karplus strong algorism. Look at this class included, http://www.libspark.org/svn/as3/SiOPM/trunk/src/org/si/sound/synthesizers/PMGuitarSynth.as - as you can see the code is marked (NOT IMPLEMENTED) however, experiment with the whole code library *not as a SWC, and uncomment the implementation. As I'd mentioned before, this is complex stuff, Ascension Systems Wonderfl. link is a good helper too.

Comment: The SCION link in this answer is dead.